# Switch color in a textarea between specified symbols

Tags: javascript, jquery

Asked before but not really same. You guys said it's impossible to switch specified Color in a textarea. So I have seen some. I would like to make an BBCode editor highlight. Between the "[" and the "]" will be colored in any color, the rest will be normal. I am currently only starting learning javascript. *Thanks for coming help!*

And what is difference between JQuery and JavaScript?

Comment: JQuery is JavaScript...

Comment: jQuery is a library which is written in JavaScript. You can check their website for more information http://jquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

first javascript is the main scripting language of the web.
And JQuery one of the librairie write in javascript to help developper to code faster and go forward with the language.

you can't do what you want directly in the textarea. For that you will need to add class in css in your text to render it as you want. You will need to externalize your text rendering.

What you will need to do what you want it's :

> 1- recover the textarea value in javascript (or JQuery it depend if you used it)
>
> 2- create a parser for you text that take each [] and apply a specific css class to render the color
>
> 3- display it in the dom. in javascript you will need to manipulate the site structure to make appear your text with your color where you want